# How to make subdomain in windows 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis, subdomain

i have website http://eshop200.com/
this website got capability of host multiple shop sites with in...
Now issue i am facing is that when we create sub site like this http://pk.eshop200.com/
its working on production server... where as the code version i am running on windows 7.

I have stuck in a situation the error is occuring on subdomain site...

to reproduce that on my local machine... don't no what to do..

any one help in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reproduce the effect of wildcard subdomains on the localhost in a windows platform.  However, you can make it work for specified subdomains.  Just edit your hosts file inside c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Answer (score 1):

On your development machine, you can created a [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) entry that makes `pk.eshop200.com` point to the loopback address 127.0.0.1. Then, you should be able to access your local development server through `http://pk.eshop.200.com:[port]` in addition to `http://127.0.0.1:[port]`.